# JS add suffix integer and rotate from 1 to 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have to change suffix for class `.background-1` to `.background-2` etc. And after 4 it goes back to 1. Like a carousel.

My trigger is click and it can be seen bellow:

```
$('.arrow-next').click(function () {
        // Here should be the code
});
```

Comment: I would split on `-`, parseInt the number and modulus by 4 and add 1, finally re-join.

Comment: I was trying currentSlide.removeClass('sample-1') and prevSlide.addClass('sample-2') but I can't figure out how to rotate it or how to count clicks. @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic solution using [Element#className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className), [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Idea is to get the element, get the full className and dynamically increment the number by replacing it with the next number (using modulo to make sure it doesn't go over the max number of backgrounds available).

The `Math.max` is after the increment gets to `5` to ensure that we don't start with `0`.

```js
const limit = 5;
$('.arrow-next').click(function() {
  const ele = $(".background").get(0);

  ele.className = ele
    .className
    .replace(
      /background-([0-9])/g, 
      (_, p1) => 'background-' + Math.max((Number(p1) + 1) % limit, 1)
    );
});
```

```css
.background-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.background-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.background-3 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.background-4 {
  background-color: green;
}

.background {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background toto background-1">

</div>

<button class="arrow-next">
  click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do...

```
const $carousel = $('.carousel');
$('.arrow-next').click(function() {
  if ($carousel.classList.contains('background-1')) {
    $el.classList.remove('background-1');
    $el.classList.add('background-2');
  } else if ($carousel.classList.contains('background-2')) {
    $el.classList.remove('background-2');
    $el.classList.add('background-3');
  } else if ($carousel.classList.contains('background-3')) {
    $el.classList.remove('background-3');
    $el.classList.add('background-4');
  } else if ($carousel.classList.contains('background-4')) {
    $el.classList.remove('background-4');
    $el.classList.add('background-1');
  }
});
```

Comment: He has 4 backgrounds, this will only work for 2 backgrounds + it's really static.. what if he has 5 or 6 backgrounds all of a sudden?

Comment: And "...My trigger is click".. :)

Comment: this doesn't fully answer the question, it won't work with more than 4 slides and it's bad code practice as it's really static